# How can I concatenate the slicing window data for different trials during time series data preparation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, time-series, lstm, data-preprocessing

I am preparing the time series data for LSTM training. I have time-series data for different participants and have sliced them using sliding windows. I was wonder how to concatenate them to form the final dataset for model training.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

participant1 = np.arange(0,40,1).reshape(10,4) #time * features
participant2 = np.arange(40,84,1).reshape(11,4) #time * features

window_size=2
input1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(participant1)
input1 = input1.window(window_size, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)

input2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(participant2)
input2 = input2.window(window_size, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)

dataset = tf.concat(input1, input2)

ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (<WindowDataset shapes: DatasetSpec(TensorSpec(shape=(4,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None), TensorShape([])), types: DatasetSpec(TensorSpec(shape=(4,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None), TensorShape([]))>) with an unsupported type (<class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.WindowDataset'>) to a Tensor.
```

Answer (score 1):

tf.concat needs tensor value, not dataset. For dataset:

```
dataset = input1.concatenate(input2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. It also does not work. AttributeError: 'DatasetSpec' object has no attribute 'most_specific_compatible_shape'

Comment: @ZhengliangXia I ran your code in TensorFlow 2.6 without error

Comment: Oh, really? My version is 2.3. I will try to upgrade my tf. Thank you very much!